# With something is ~ - grammatical construction

Tags: grammar

> The process of relational database model design is the method used to create a relational database model. This process is mathematical in nature, but very simple, and is called normalization. **With the process of normalization are** a number of distinct steps called Normal Forms. Normal Forms are: 1st Normal Form (1NF), 2nd Normal Form (2NF), 3rd Normal Form (3NF), Boyce-Codd Normal Form (BCNF), 4th Normal Form (4NF), 5th Normal Form (5NF), and Domain Key Normal Form (DKNF). That is quite a list.

Obviously it is quite clear what it means (there are a number of distinct steps when it comes to normalization), but I still, with your help, would like to see some other examples that use this type of grammatical construction. The pattern appears to be as the following:

> **with something is ~**

So, will you please show a couple examples with maybe even some explanation along the way?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You should use ***within** the process of normalization are [blah, blah]* if you're determined to have that construction. Though personally I'd rather say *the process of normalization **consists of** a number of steps...*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interestingly, when you rephrased your example, you put it in its common form.

> there are a number of distinct steps *when it comes to* normalization...

Usually *with* x *comes* y is a more common construction by far.

> With Parenthood Comes a Most Spectacular Wake-Up Call. - article title
>   All the indictors show that with a degree comes clear reduction of unemployment and clear earnings advantage. - Grading America

This is a simple type of inversion.

> A Most Spectacular Wake-Up Call Comes With Parenthood.

In fact, I don't think your example quite holds up.

*With the process of normalization are a number of distinct steps called Normal Forms.* Rearranging that, the sentence becomes

> A number of distinct steps called Normal Forms **are** with the process of normalization.

That is a highly unusual construction, and it doesn't quite make sense to me. It needs another word.